# Laravel Updating User - Admin and User only

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When updating a user's account, what is the best way to only allow the user itself and the admin to do so?

I use [multiauth](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth) and the only way I can think of is:

```
public function update($id)
{
    if (Auth::admin()->check() || Auth::user()->get()->id == $id)
    {
        // Allow update
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do so?

Comment: I think that is fine, just put that code in a filter, and do a 'before' check on it - then you can reuse it elsewhere later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you put this code depends on your architecture.

If it's a simple setup, the model might be the perfect place for it:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements .... {

    protected static function boot($id)
    {
        static::updating(function($user)
        {
            return $user->canCurrentUserUpdate();
        });
    }

    protected function canCurrentUserUpdate()
    {
        return Auth::admin()->check() || Auth::user()->get()->id == $this->id;
    }
}
```